# PHP foreach using an array sent via an ajax request failing. Correct data sent to function

Tags: php

In an ajax request, i'm sending an array of member_id's in order to get back the screen names. The member id's are stored as follows:

```
var member_id = [];
    Ext.each(selected_rows, function(item) {
        member_id.push(item.data.member_id);
    });
```

I'm then sending them to a retrieve_members function

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    action: 'retrieve_members',
                    member_id: member_id,
                    success_fn: function(response) {
                    //do stuff
                    }
                }); //end ajaxRequest
```

Firebug shows this when call is sent:

```
action  retrieve_members
member_id   45FA3B10-4546-B9F7-D23
member_id   9627B65B-4D82-B2E8-4CE
```

In the retrieve_members function:

```
function retrieve_members($request) {
$member_ids = substr($request->member_id,0,-1);

    foreach($member_ids as $member_id) {

        $current_member = Member::retrieveById($request->db, $member_id);
        $member_list = $current_member->getGroupMembers();
        $members = array();
        foreach ( $member_list as $member ) {

            $member_list[] = array(
                'id' => $member->id,
                'screen_name' => $member->screen_name,
            );
        }
    }
return json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'member_list' => $member_list));
}
```

If I remove the foreach and replace the following line:

```
$member = Member::retrieveById($request->db, $request->$member_id);
```

I get the correct data back for 1 member. I know the "substr($request->member_id,0,-1);" may be wrong, but I've made many attempts to pass the correct member_ids to the foreach. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, but as this stands it will member_list will always come back null. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:
print_r($request->member_id); returns the following error:

```
identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
[Break On This Error]   

(9627B65B-4D82-B2E8-4CE)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `print_r($request->member_id);` prints?

Comment: Updated with the error print_r($request->member_id); is giving

Comment: I think your `strpos` line is wrong, but it doesn't look like your javascript is sending everything through either.

Comment: Updated with the ajax call, I can redirect this question at extjs/javascript. But the print_r error when firebug shows the id's being sent to the function confuses me even more.

Comment: The `identifier starts immediately after numeric literal` error is a javascript error that usually means you didn't wrap a string with quotes. That doesn't really seem to apply here though. I wonder if it's a bug in extjs? Maybe try `member_id.push("'" + item.data.member_id + "'");
` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be overwriting some variables. Maybe try:

```
function retrieve_members($request) {
$member_ids = substr($request->member_id,0,-1);

    foreach($member_ids as $member_id) {

        $member = Member::retrieveById($request->db, $member_id);
        $member_list = $member->getGroupMembers();
        $members = array();
        foreach ( $member_list as $tempMember ) {
            array_push($members,array(
                'id' => $tempMember->id,
                'screen_name' => $tempMember->screen_name,
            ));
        }
    }
return json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'member_list' => $members));
}
```

Comment: the double member variables was a mistake on my part when transcribing the code to stackoverflow, sorry! Thanks for catching that regardless. In my actual code this was not the case. Updated my original post.